# What is the best usage of Dispose for "Entity Framework"?

Tags: entity-framework, frameworks, dispose

What is the true usage of dispose ? 
This is first (my) approach:

```
 public class RequestService : IDisposable
        {
            requestDBEntities db;
            public RequestService() //Constructor
            {
                db = new requestDBEntities ();
            }
       public List<RequestStatus> ddlFill()
            {
               return (from rs in db.reqStatus select rs).ToList();
            }
            //Some Insert,Update,Delete methods {}...

        public void Dispose()
            {
                db.Dispose(); //<--Dispose requestDBEntities(); 
                GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            }
```

And second approach:

```
    public class RequestService : IDisposable
            {
               requestDBEntities db;
               public List<RequestStatus> ddlFill()
                {
              using (db = new requestDBEntities())
                    return (from rs in db.reqStatus select rs).ToList();
                }
            //Some Insert,Update,Delete methods {}...

            public void Dispose()
                {
                    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
                }
```

Page Code-behind:

```
            using (RequestService _reqService = new RequestService ())
               {
                ddlRequestStatus.DataSource = _reqService.ddlFill();
                ddlRequestStatus.DataBind();

                //Some Insert,Update,Delete operations...
               }
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult (impossible) to say which is the better approach, since we don't know your exact design choice. From the perspective of a simple app, it may seem that the two examples are equivalent (more or less), but they really do behave in entirely different ways.

The fundamental question here is: Should the lifetime of `db` be comparable to the lifetime of its enclosing `RequestService` instance?

If yes, then the first code example is the way to do things. Resources will be managed as expected (`db` disposes its stuff at the same time the `RequestService` object is asked to dispose of its resources), and the lifetime of the two will be pretty much identical (`db` is constructed in the `RequestService` constructor, and `db` become collectable as soon as its `RequestService` object becomes collectable).

However, if the answer is "no", then the second example is (almost) the way to do things - since you generate a collection view of the `RequestStatus` object from `db`, you really have no reason to keep `db` around any longer. However, to make this a bit better, may I suggest restricting the scope of `db` to within the `ddlFill` method:

```
public List<RequestStatus> ddlFill()
{
    using (var db = new requestDBEntities())
         return (from rs in db.reqStatus select rs).ToList();
}
```

No need for an extraneous class member when a stack value suffices.

Comment: Thank you for your interest, this information is very descriptive for me.

Answer (score 0):

What for in second example you have declared requestDBEntities db; at class level instead of having it as a stack variable?

Comparing your approaches, the question is - are you ready to create requestDBEntities on each call? If you are - second approach is better, in fact if there is nothing else you haven'y posted - you don't need dispose at all. But you'll have extra time penalty on instantiating/releasing requestDBEntities on each call.